# Show Applications is different between accounts

Tags: .desktop

Here are two screenshots of the "Show Applications" search function launched by the nine dot icon on the screen's lower left. Each screen shot is from a different account. There is the "test" account, and my main "stephen" account.

In the search result for the test account there is a "Software" section. This section is missing in the stephen's account search result. What can account for this difference? What directory is the "Software" section's search result from? I thought at first it would be in /usr/share/applications/ . But here is evidence it is not.

I have a suspicion this is a manifestation of other problems the stephen account has which the test account does not. One of them is that no icon in the stephen's account desktop can be set to trusted. In the test account they can be.

test account:
[image: Screenshot, Show Applications, Flameshot, test account]

stephen account:
[image: Screenshot, Show Applications, Flameshot, stephen account]

Comment: I have been working on the actual problem for about 1 year. Nothing I have tried has worked, and that includes using the gio command. No answer has come forward in any thread I have started about it. Yesterday I downloaded the sourced code for the entire Ubuntu kernel, and I will examine it for an answer. This difference I post here is something I have recently noticed. I post it here because the answer to this mystery might possibly solve the problem.

Comment: This thread is about my attempt to use gio to solve it: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/+question/706013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When searching in the applications overview, it will show matching files.

The `stephen` account is including matching files under this user's `/home/stephen` folder.

The `test` account doesn't have access to read the other user's home folder, so those files won't be included in the search results.

Because there are different search results, this will affect the results that are displayed between the two different users.

Comment: It is the test account that shows search results the stephen account does not. If the "Software" section is not from a file path that is common to both accounts, then what is the complete file path in each account that the "Show Applications" search function looks in to display results in the "Software" section?

Comment: The "software" hits are duplicates of the huge icons at the top. They are shown twice on the test account because there aren't as many hits as the stephen account for the reason I mentioned in this answer.

Comment: Is there a way to get a larger search result "Show Applications" window that would show more search results?

Comment: My assumption based on the information you've given is that there aren't any more results with that criteria. The test account won't ever show the results from the other user's home folder because it doesn't have permissions to read other user's home folders.